# How to divide dataset into some blocks and choose the largest one?

Tags: r

In R, I try to divide `n=10000` iid observations into `100` blocks and each block with size `n/100=10`. Then for each block I want to choose the largest value for each block as a new dataset with size `100`. How to achieve this point in R?

For example,

```
#sample data
n<-10000
exp_data=rexp(n, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `tidyverse` way could be:

1. We first transform to a tibble with `as_tibble` from `tibble` package.
2. Generate groups of 10 with `gl()` function.
3. Split our tibble of 10000 rows to a list of tibbles with 100 tibble
4. Apply the `map` from `purrr` package with the `slice_max` function (`dplyr` package) to get the max value from each of the 100 new tibbles.
5. Finally use `bind_rows()` to get them all in your new tibble with 100 rows:

Note (`dplyr`, `tibble`, `purrr`) are in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
exp_data %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(group =as.integer(gl(n(),100,n()))) %>% 
  group_split(group) %>%
  map(., ~slice_max(., order_by = value)) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

```
  <dbl> <int>
 1  5.81     1
 2  6.42     2
 3  4.46     3
 4  4.07     4
 5  5.35     5
 6  5.85     6
 7  4.03     7
 8  5.13     8
 9  4.71     9
10  4.71    10
# … with 90 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But how to get these maximal values as `numeric`?

Comment: I just add `exp_max<-...` before `exp_data %>%`. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a column that provides the grouping, in this example assume the groups are sequential (i.e. first 100 values belong to the first group, second 100 to the second group and so on):

```
df = data.frame(values = exp_data,
                group = floor((1:length(exp_data))/100))
```

Now, just use `tapply` to get the maximum:

```
with(df, tapply(X = values, 
                INDEX = group, 
                FUN = max))
```

Comment: Can this way be repeated for many times? For example, I do 30 replication to sample `n=10000` and have `100` blocks and then choose the maximal value for each block.